# installing pygame over anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, anaconda

I am trying to install pygame over anaconda.  My OS is windows 7 64 bit and I downloaded the following files:

pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win32.whl
pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
prebuilt-x64-pygame-1.9.2-20150907.zip
pygame-1.9.2a0-hg_ea3b3bb8714a.win32-py2.7.msi
pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py2.7.msi

I get this error after "pip install pygame":
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions:  )   Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Download the wheel file that is appropriate for your system, then use `pip install C:\\path\to\wheel\file` to install it. Just downloading a bunch of files will not help.

Comment: I put "pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win32.whl" in the directory C:\pygamefolder and then tried: cd C:\pygamefolder followed by pip install pygame     still the same error

Comment: In your question you wrote that you have a 64 bit system. Why would you choose the 32 bit binary? Also, please read my previous comment again carefully. `pip install pygame` is simply not the correct way of installing in your case. Copying files and switching directories will not change that.

Comment: can you be more specific.  I am new to python and perhaps I am not doing everything correctly.  I did put the 64 version wheel in the directory  C:\pygamefolder and then "pip install C:\pygamefolder" but it says : Directory 'C:\\pygamefolder' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when installing pygame with anaconda. I believe that if you go into the terminal on anaconda and type

```
Pip install pygame
```

It installs the latest version of pygame into your environment